# Two simultaneous AVAudioSessions

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession, audiotoolbox

I have an app that uses WebRTC for voice chat.
After a lot of troubleshooting I came to the conclusion that whenever I receive a stream, the WebRTC will set the AVAudioSession shared instance to the following:
`try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .voiceChat, options: .allowBluetooth)`

I want to play an audio file (about a second long) and if I simply load it and do `player.play()`, it won't play. If I try to set the category to `.playback` or anything that would make sense for an audio file, the stream's audio will stop playing.

I also tried to create a new AVAudioSession instance but once the audio file plays, the stream's audio will stop.

Is there a way for me to get the audio file to play without affecting the stream's audio and its configuration?

Here's the full code

```
    private func playTapSound() {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: App.AudioFile.emojiTapSound, withExtension: "mp3") else { return }

        do {
            let audioSesson = AVAudioSession()
            try audioSesson.setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
            try audioSesson.setActive(true)

            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)

            guard let player = audioPlayer else { return }

            player.play()

        } catch let error {
            LogManager.shared.print("Error - playing emoji tap audio -", error.localizedDescription, type: [.Error, .Audio])
        }
//        var chime1URL: NSURL?
//        var chime1ID: SystemSoundID = 0
//        let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "emojiTapSound", ofType: "wav")
//        chime1URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)
//        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(chime1URL!, &chime1ID)
//        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(0)
    }
```

I also tried using the AudioToolBox but for some reason it only played on the simulator. I verified that it's not my phone's settings by trying one of Apple's preloaded sounds and it worked.

Comment: There can only be one session. This is an app wide setting. Your sound should play with the category set to playAndRecord. What happens if you get rid of your session code?

Comment: @LouFranco I won't hear it. I tried setting the player's volume to 1.0 as well just in case.

Comment: Are you sure the MP3 is good?

Comment: I tried mp3 for AVAudio and wav for AudioToolbox. @LouFranco

Comment: Same issue, I am facing too. did you get any solution around it?